# How to use Hibernate inside a JSP file?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I have a class to handle Businesses that I build with Hibernate and it works great.

For example, if I want to a new Business, I simply call `addBusiness` method.

Example:

```
package implementations;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import entities.*;

public class Controller {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactroy() {
        if(sessionFactory == null) 
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Users users = Users.getInstance();

        Businesses.getInstance().addBusiness(new Business(3, "", "", "", 1.1, 1.1));
    }
}
```

I have a web application for manage my database, so I tried to call this function from the `JSP` file:

```
<%@page import="entities.Business"%>
<%@page import="implementations.Businesses"%>
<%@page import="entities.Coupon, implementations.Coupons "%>
<%
/*  String bname = request.getParameter("bname");
    String image = request.getParameter("image");
    String details = request.getParameter("details");
    String latitude = request.getParameter("latitude");
    String longitude = request.getParameter("longitude");

    if(bname == null || image == null || details == null || latitude == null || longitude == null) {
        out.println("You have missing arguments!");
    } else {
        Businesses b = Businesses.getInstance();
        b.addBusiness(new Business(0, details, image, bname, Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude)));
    }
*/
    Businesses.getInstance().addBusiness(new Business(1, "", "", "", 1.1, 1.1));
    %>
```

I'm getting this error in the console:

```
Dec 12, 2013 9:08:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin;.
Dec 12, 2013 9:08:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:firstXDw' did not find a matching property.
Dec 12, 2013 9:08:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 12, 2013 9:08:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 12, 2013 9:08:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 435 ms
Dec 12, 2013 9:08:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 12, 2013 9:08:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Dec 12, 2013 9:08:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 12, 2013 9:08:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 12, 2013 9:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 334 ms
Dec 12, 2013 9:08:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/firstXDw] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.addnewbusiness_jsp._jspService(addnewbusiness_jsp.java:75)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And this error on the web:

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:534)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:442)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
    org.apache.jsp.views.addnewbusiness_jsp._jspService(addnewbusiness_jsp.java:82)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
    org.apache.jsp.views.addnewbusiness_jsp._jspService(addnewbusiness_jsp.java:75)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    org.apache.jsp.views.addnewbusiness_jsp._jspService(addnewbusiness_jsp.java:75)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.12 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
```

Why is the problem and how can I fix it?

this is my project hierarchy.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session

It seems you are missing hibernate.core jar...

Comment: I moved the source to the wrong folder and it freaked me out.. i knew it's the problem but it drove me mad it didn't solve it..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an active Hibernate session/transaction open. Look into the [Open Session In View](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView?_sscc=t) pattern. In that pattern, you wrap all requests that will need to access Hibernate (using a Filter as in the linked example). The transaction is closed after the view is finished rendering.

Comment: The link in my answer contains sample code to set up a Filter. Then map the filter in your web.xml so that it applies to any requests that will need to use Hibernate (it also has a sample web.xml entry for this).

Comment: Sorry but I still not understand